# WordPress Theme Oddity

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I have applied a theme called Karma to my WordPress instance and there is an issue (which they deny) that I've had for awhile now and just can't seem to figure out with its CSS.

The problem is that my website, [www.LiveCarePC.com](http://www.LiveCarePC.com) is a responsive site. When it resizes for mobile or a tablet, .jqslider seems to fail to resize itself properly. It just becomes a gray bar that bothers you.

Desktop view:

[image]

Mobile View:

[image]

Karma Theme Mobile View (Live Preview on http://themes.truethemes.net/Karma/homepage-jquery-2-2):

[image]

Any help would GREATLY be appreciated. You can inspect the site and see its source there, obviously.

*Note: I've reinstalled Wordpress and the theme itself as well as all the plugins so it's not that. I'm just looking for the solution in the code.

Comment: I just say the site;...the slider seem to work fine in tablet...mobile...though needs styling

Comment: I posted screenshots for you...

Comment: if you do not like the gray bar why use a media query to hide it at a certain width??

Comment: I'm trying to have it expand like it's supposed to, to the size of the text below or a fixed width so you can actually see the words, but it doesn't seem to do that correctly in its responsive design even though its supposed to. I'll revise the original post with an image showing the way its supposed to be.

Comment: looks like you got the styling correct

Comment: Looks exactly like it's supposed to be, have you tried clearing your cache etc?

Comment: I was able to fix it about 2 hours ago. It was a bug with one of the many css files it uses. I will post how I did it now for anyone else running into this bug and submit it to the developer. Love Opera's Dragonfly :)

Thank you everyone for your help on this! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else running into this error, it seems it's a bug in one of the css files. Below is the fix.

In the karma-royal-blue.css file, you must comment out one of the lines as seen below.

```
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/* HEADER 
/*------------------------------------------------*/
#header .header-holder {background:#182947 url(../images/skins/karma-royal-blue/bg-header-holder.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x !important;} 

/* .big-banner #header .header-holder {background:#182947 url(../images/skins/karma-royal-blue/bg-big-header-holder.png) 0 0 repeat-x !important;} */

.top-block {background:#13223C !important;}
```

The line that's commented out is the line that, well, needs to be commented out. That fixes the error.

This fix applies to the Royal Blue color scheme in the Karma Wordpress theme. It may apply to others as well.